# Which parameters should I declare as sql placeholders?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, placeholder

Should I use a placeholder for every parameter even if it a parameter is always same? And how about nulls? Should I use placeholders for them also?

I'm interested in avoiding preparing and enable caching of the query. I'm using mysql, php and pdo but I think this is the same also with other databases. Security is not a deal because the parameters in the question are hard coded.

Case 1: Should I use a placeholder for visibility or is hard coded value 1 better?
select * from table where visibility=1 and product=:id

Case 2: Should I use a placeholder for null? (and is it the same for both cases?)
select * from t1 where color is null
update t1 set color=null where product=:id

Answer (score 1):

if parameters are hardcoded, there is no use for the placeholders at all.
Query caching is enabled by mysql by default, so, you have no worry about it.

So, if there are really no dynamically changed parameters, there is no use in preparing and executing. Just use PDO query method.

However, the question from your title, `Which parameters should I declare as sql placeholders?` is muhch more interesting.

in terms of that clumsy PDO library, you have to use placeholders for data only. 
but in terms of creating SQL queries dynamically, you have to use appropriate placeholders for **every** variable part of query.

Comment: `Those examples were simplified.` it's your fault. as well as misleading `I'm interested in avoiding preparing` statement which cannot be true when `There are usually both dynamically changing and non-changing variables.` you have to rephrase your question to make it less vague. and there is no placeholder for null value, if it's your question

Comment: sorry. i didn't want to make you angry :(

Comment: I weren't angry a bit :) only I wanted to say is: you have to rephrase your question to make it less vague. if you have :id dynamic, there is no way to escape binding, isn't it? so, what the question then?

Comment: This is not clear to me, that's why it sounds confusing :) If I have both hard coded values and binded variables in my query and even if those hard coded values are always the same, are the statement always prepared and not retrieved from cache? So, is the example 1 always prepared? But if I used placeholder :one instead of 1 (number one) would it be better for performance?

Comment: how many times you are running this query within one script instance?

Comment: as for hte performance it would be ALL the same. no difference. and no need to worry about performance without a reason

Comment: Some of the command I use just once and some may be used 1000 times. I'm using just one function calldb that I call for all sql commands, for example $array = calldb("select id,name from products where quantity<:qt",array(":qt" => 10)). The system have maybe 1000 different sql statements and I'm translating it from classic asp & sql server to use php & mysql. The system is huge. Many of the statements are very simple and some of them are very long & complicated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3734/discussion-between-viljun-and-col-shrapnel)

Comment: I am asking you NOT how many DIFFERENT queries you have. but how many times you are running THE SAME query within one script instance. A sensible script would run each query only once. So, you benefit from prepared statements NONE.